# Accessibility in android issue

Tags: android, accessibility

I have a simple layout which shows 4 textview , out of which 1 textview is clickable(in my case it can be any clickable view).Accessibility works fine (i-e it read out all the 4 views)if none of the view is clickable, but making any view clickable- it skip that particular view which is clickable. I need that When my Linear layout is in focus it should read out all its child view whether or not they are clickable.

```
  <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.accessibility.MainActivity" > 
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.example.accessibility.MainActivity" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hello_world" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="another textview" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="82dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="Button1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="106dp"
            android:text="Button2" />
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Can anyone suggest how this could be done

Comment: I think I don´t get You..I´m not sure about what You want, but if You want to get the clickable statement of a view, You can call yourView.isClickable().....

Comment: I request you to just make a simple app with this layout and wd accessibility on and see the behaviour. Next remove  android:clickable="true" from 3rd textview and then see the behaviour. You will get what I need to convey

Comment: first, give Your LinearLayout that holds the textViews an ID, then get all childs from this view and check if they are clickable, if not setClickable(false)....is that what You think of?

Comment: But I do not want to make them clickable  false. As it will perform some operation. All I need is that It should speak out -> Hello world, another textview, button1 and button 2 in sequence, it should bot skip button1. At present it is skipping button1

Comment: so please show some relevant code, to get more information what You have done...

Comment: There is just a single activity which is having this code @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       
    } nothing else. Talk back functionality is ON thats it

Comment: So You have to do more work here. We can´t give You all the code You need, just can give You hints. What You want, You can do with a for loop for example. Inside this loop check if view is clickable, if yes, speak out, if not, don´t speak....

Comment: i got a work around and it work fine now.... I agree wd you that u cant provide me the code and even i dnt expect that.. thanks for bearing wd me... i will update my solution soon....cheers...

Comment: This is working as intended. Actionable (e.g. focusable or clickable) views are traversed and spoken separately from non-actionable views. You should not attempt to work around this behavior.

Comment: I came to know that eventually but I needed to show it that way ... anyways

Answer (score 0):

In the view that has been impoverished of Accessibility focus try to experiment with either android:focusable or
android:focusableInTouchMode or both by setting them to true